# Printing on the same line in Fortran

Tags: fortran

```
 if (mod(n,2) == 0) then
       write(stdout, *) "Even"
    else
       write(stdout, *) "Odd "
  end if
```

I want to print `Even Odd Even Odd`.
Why can't I use the $ descriptor for this?

Comment: Don't use ` for code-blocks. Click on the `{}` icon in the editing window instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `$` descriptor in your code!

But no, there is no `$` descriptor in standard Fortran. Some compilers have it as an extension and other do not. Don't use it if you want portable programs.

Fortran 90 standard conforming way is using the non-advancing O/O with `advance='no'`. Note that it requires a format, not list-directed input.

```
write(stdout, some_format, advance='no') "Even"
```

`some_format` can be `'(a)'` or `'(g0)'` or whatever applicable.

Also, for a caveat see http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#3 (summary: there can still be a record length limit).